# Dismissing multiple view-controllers

Tags: uiviewcontroller

my view-controllers digram looks like this

1. main view controller

   2. modelpresented view controller linked to a navigation controller as
      a root view controller(presented one time).

      3. push presented view controller.(can instantiateViewController and push segue to its self multiple times)

how to dismiss all view controllers back to main?

Answer (score -1):

```
navigationController.dismiss()
```